# How can I stop Blender from altering my model poses?

Tags: keyframes

[image]

Where do these keyframes keep coming from? Why does it always stop at 100?
Auto keying has been disabled the whole time and Blender eventually gets rid of some of my desired bone positions when I do certain operations. The undo buttons doesn't help anything.
Also, these auto keys are just empty. The majority of my time, I don't notice when my pose has been changed because I'm trying to test daylighting.

Comment: hard to know where it comes from, maybe switch your Dope Sheet to Action Editor, close this action and see what's happening?

Comment: @moonboots I usually just delete those keys in regardless if I'm in the dope sheet or action editor. I recently just looked at the action editor in another scene and it just shows the same thing as the dope sheet. I don't know if the keys will alter my poses again. I may comeback if this happens again.

Comment: it's weird, it looks as if you had baked your action but I suppose you didn't

Comment: @moonboots I'll give you the whole story. A was in desperate need of making the switch from Max to Blender, so imported all my models by FBX format. Up until today I started noticing this problem. Seems that these empty key frames were automatically created after importing. I think me posting this issue may be pointless since all I have to do is delete the empty keys. I won't know yet if the problem would still persist. I'm posing a model right now with deleted keys. I may update you on it.

Comment: If you find the answer, write it in the Your Answer field so that it can inform people who may meet the same problem

Answer (score 0):

So, deleting all of the keyframes that the import added on will keep Blender from deleting certain bone positions when performing certain actions during or after posing the model.